# How can I log all my command-line activity?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, unix, logging

I just had a Heisenbug that completely disappeared on me. I'm convinced that something funny must have happened when I compiled my program several days or a week ago.

But sadly, my Windows (MINGW) shell history buffer doesn't go back anywhere near that far. How can I arrange to log all my command-line activity so I can do these sorts of investigations in the future?

With Unix, of course, you can use the `script` utility. But windows does not (IME) treat files with the same care that Unix does: ie. <del>you can't `| tee logfile` an arbitrary program and expect to interact with it normally.</del> shell-windows do not represent themselves in a flexible pty interface. So based on this prejudice of mine, I haven't seriously searched for a port of the script utility.

How would a "windows" person do this?

Comment: For the record, neither does Unix. Many interactive programs expect stdin *and* stdout to be a pseudoterminal (pty), which `script` provides, but a pipe would not.

Comment: oh. thanks. I don't think that changes the balance of my opinions. But I stand corrected in fact.

Answer (score 2):

Providing you're using *bash*, you may want to have a look at [bash's HISTORY parameters](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash#n30) to improve the size of your command-line history:

- `HISTSIZE` changes the maximum number of commands available through the [`history`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/history) command
- `HISTFILESIZE` changes the maximum size of your `HISTFILE`, usually *.bash_history*. If not set, the `HISTFILE` won't be truncated at all, so you'll have your all-life history in it.
- The `histappend` option appends the new history to your history file rather than overwriting it.

Example *.bashrc*:

```
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z  "
```

`HISTTIMEFORMAT` will timestamp your history, which is very useful when investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shell buffer in emacs. The size of the buffer is then not related to the number of lines saved by the terminal.